# Symfony doctrine using IS DISTINCT FROM

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having a problem with using IS DISTINCT FROM with symfony. In my case I want sth like this

```
SELECT * FROM table orders AS o WHERE o.orderer_id IS DISTINCT FROM o.operator_id
```

It works fine if I run by using pgAdmin(Postgresql), but I don't know how to write with symfony doctrine. I tried to search about this, but no result for me, so anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe it's not implemented (since it's dialect, not a part of ANSI SQL), so you can either extend doctrine with your very own `IS DISTINCT FROM` operator or just expand it to `IS NULL` + `<>` checks manually. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks zerkms, I achieve this by

```
   $queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->isNotNull('tem.operator'),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->neq('tem.orderer', 'tem.operator'),
                $queryBuilder->expr()->neq('tem.enterprise', 'tem.operator')
            )
        ),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->isNull('tem.operator')
    ));
```